# Error during deploy from pipeline on firebase

Tags: firebase, gitlab, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment

I try to deploy my angular application on firebase using gitlab pipeline.

I followed this [guide](https://medium.com/evenbit/automatically-deploy-to-firebase-with-gitlab-ci-546f194c44d8) and I write a gitlab-ci file more simplified for starting.

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node-modules/

stages:
  - deploy

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: development
  script:
    - npm install -g firebase-tools
    - npm install
    - npm run builddev
    - npm run deploy
  only:
    - master
```

Everything work until last command when I have this error

[image]

but if from terminal I run

> firebase deploy --project test-1c121

everything work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `package.json` file in `scripts` section. You probably have a typo in `deploy` because npm runs into problem with running **firebse** command and you want to run **firebase**.

Comment: I'm sorry to have posted this stupid question :( . I swear that I don't see the typo. No work perfectly

Comment: This site exists for seeking help and providing it, don't worry! Everybody makes stupid mistakes!